# Dynamically change items in comboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have 2 `comboBox` objects with same items specified via Design redactor.

If any specific item is selected in the first comboBox, it must be removed from the second.

What I currently do:

1) Added this

```
static ComboBox.ObjectCollection defaultCollection;
```

2) On `Form_Load`

```
defaultCollection = comboBoxRange1.Items;
```

3)

```
private void comboBoxRange1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBoxRange2.Enabled = true;
    ComboBox.ObjectCollection copyCollection = defaultCollection;
    copyCollection.RemoveAt(comboBoxRange1.SelectedIndex);
    comboBoxRange2.DataSource = copyCollection;
}
```

But after this I got selected item removed from both comboBoxes and `defaultCollection` becomes modified. How do I fix it? Do I need to make copies of collections or manually reassemble values on every change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ComboBox.ObjectCollection copyCollection = defaultCollection;` doesn't do what you want it to do: it doesn't **copy**, but set a reference to `defaultCollection`.

Here are some more explanation on whether a variable is **set by reference** or **set by value**: if the data is a **[value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)**, basically struct and enumerations (say `int`, which is an alias of `System.Int32`), the **value** of the data will be **copied** when doing an assignment; if the data is a  **[reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx)**, basically classes, interfaces and delegates, the reference to the object will be **passed** to the LHS when doing an assignment.

As for your question, yes, you need to make a copy to keep `defaultCollection` unmodified.

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating a copy of the collection, you are simply creating a new variable that references the same collection as the first. It does not matter which variable you use to remove the item, you still have only one collection referenced by 2 variables and bound to 2 combo boxes.